# freenect /camera/depth/points topic not published under a group namespace tag

Tags: octomap, ros-kinetic, freenect, namespace, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am currently running [Octomap](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_mapping?distro=melodic) on my Qbot using ROS kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04. (My plan is to run ROS navigation stack using the built octomap and create a multi-robot system)
Because of the multi-robot networking requirement I need to name my robots uniquely, and I tried doing this using both  and  tags. While my launch file works as expected without the namespace parameter, it does not give the expected result with the namespace. I generated rqt_graphs for my working and not working programs and figured out that /camera/depth/points topic is not published so that it can output into the octomap_server node.

This is my first launch file which works accurately.

```
    <launch>
        <!-- run kobuki base -->
        <include file="$(find kobuki_node)/launch/minimal.launch"/>

        <!-- tf config -->
        <include file="$(find multi_robot_exploration)/launch/tf_pub.launch" />

        <!-- run kinect -->
        <include file="$(find freenect_launch)/launch/freenect.launch"/>

        <!-- run octomap_server -->
        <include file="$(find octomap_server)/launch/octomap_mapping.launch"/>
</launch>
```

And here is the relevant rqt_graph (generated without running RViz)
[image: image description]

This is my second launch file which I wrote by including the **group tag and a namespace**

```
     <launch>
    <group ns="qbot1">
        <!-- run kobuki base -->
        <include file="$(find kobuki_node)/launch/minimal.launch"/>

        <!-- tf config -->
        <include file="$(find multi_robot_exploration)/launch/tf_pub.launch" />

        <!-- run kinect -->
        <include file="$(find freenect_launch)/launch/freenect.launch"/>

        <!-- run octomap_server -->
        <include file="$(find octomap_server)/launch/octomap_mapping.launch"/>
    </group>
</launch>
```

And this is the relevant rqt_graph
[image: image description]

It looks like the /camera/depth/points topic is not available in the second setting, and hence it cannot publish to octomap_server. But it is available when I launch the file without  tag. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Note: I use the standard ROS packages for [Octomap](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_mapping?distro=melodic), [kobuki_node](http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki_node), and [freenect](http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_launch) drivers. I have located all of them within my working directory and sourced them. I have tried adding namespace variable as different include tags also.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319040/freenect-/camera/depth/points-topic-not-published-under-a-group-namespace-tag./) by [TharushiDeSilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/40232/tharushidesilva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2019-03-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-03-21**:
Hi,

1. Do you see any errors / warnings when you launch the qbot1 launch file?
2. What is the output when you execute

   rosnode info /qbot1/camera/camera_nodelet_manager

?

**Comment by [TharushiDeSilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/40232/tharushidesilva/) on 2019-03-22**:\

1. There are no additional warnings. (Same warnings as the first one - Could not find any compatible depth output mode for 1. Falling back to default depth output mode 1)
2. In the info log I can see these relevant information

   Node [/qbot1/camera/camera_nodelet_manager]
   Publications:

   - /qbot1/camera/depth/points [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2]
   - /qbot1/camera/depth_registered/points [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2]

The full log is published here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XYYna5UhFS2BtggB_JWlfWVLuZR_NUr9/view?usp=sharing

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-03-22**:
That means the nodelet has advertised the topic

```
/qbot1/camera/depth/points
```

The next two steps to debug are

1. Check if the nodelet is actually publishing to `/qbot1/camera/depth/points` by executing 'rostopic echo /qbot1/camera/depth/points'
2. If messages are published, then try `rosnode info /qbot1/octomap_server` to see if octomap server has subscribed to the proper topic

**Comment by [TharushiDeSilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/40232/tharushidesilva/) on 2019-03-22**:
The data stream is published into the topic /qbot1/camera/depth/points

The octomap_server seems to subscribe to the topic without the namespace.

```
 Node [/qbot1/octomap_server]
    Subscriptions: 
     * /camera/depth/points [unknown type]
```

Guess I have to look inside octomap_server node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out that `qbot1/camera/depth/points` topic is successfully published through `freenect.launch` launcher, but the `octomap_server` is subscribing to `/camera/depth/points` topic. The `OctomapServer.cpp` source code looks for the absolute namespace and it does not read the `qbot1` prefix.
According to the remapping that I am using, the code line 177 of `OctomapServer.cpp` is changed like this.

```
m_pointCloudSub = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> (m_nh, "/camera/depth/points", 5);
```

Because of the `/` in front of the subscribed topic, it always looks for a topic that starts as `/camera/depth/points`.

This should be correctly used as;

```
 m_pointCloudSub = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> (m_nh, "camera/depth/points", 5);
```

---

Originally posted by [TharushiDeSilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/40232/tharushidesilva/) with karma: 79 on 2019-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0